# Does blocking app notifications stop app from accessing internet?

Tags: notifications, push-notifications

On Android smartphone, we can hold finger on any notification from app and after clicking on "i" it shows option to block any further notification from the app. Say for example, I do this for gmail then it won't show me notifs about new email.

Does this disable the app from accessing the internet or only the display of notifications is disabled?

Comment: How hard was it to research (not search) this on your own, I wonder. And why did you think internet has anything to do with hiding notifications?

Comment: @Firelord i just wanted to be sure. i thought it was like answered but wasnt sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says - notifications only. The app will continue to work as usual, just won't show any notifications until you enable them again.

Comment: The app will even keep creating the notifications in the same way: Android will just ignore them instead of showing them to you.